# Warning occurred when I run my jar on linux

Tags: java, linux, jar

When I run a jar it comes a warning.

I runned my jar successfully  on linux.

After , few minutes it comes like this

```
(Java:4714): GDK-Warning**: XSetErrorHandler() called with a GDK error trap pushed. Don't do that.
```

[image: error]

After this warning the jar did not runned .

Why this comes like this ?

Give a solution for this?

Comment: The warning is unrelated to your problem.  `Killed` suggests your program was terminated by another process, possibly a `kill` command issued by another shell.

Answer (score 2):

Run it with `jdk.gtk.version=3` option as shown below:

```
$ java -Djdk.gtk.verbose=true -Djdk.gtk.version=3 ...
```

Check [JDK-8198654](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198654) for more details.

Comment: Where to use this `
    $ java -Djdk.gtk.verbose=true -Djdk.gtk.version=3 ...` ?

Comment: You can include the option `-Djdk.gtk.verbose=true -Djdk.gtk.version=3` anywhere in your command e.g. `java -Djdk.gtk.verbose=true -Djdk.gtk.version=3 --module-path /usr/share...` Here, I've included it in the starting.